# Alterative to Call log permission Android

Tags: android, calllog

What alternative can I use for call log according to google updated call log restriction policy.My app needs call logs for its normal functioning in Android.

Comment: What do you need call logs for?

Comment: If your App is based on CallLog then you can submit a Request to Google to let them allow your App to use this Permission when it will be uploaded to PlayStore.

Comment: I have already filled the form but that will work only till 9 of january.